# Change results page for a people search web part

Tags: search-results, people-search

I've created a search centre sub site within my main site collection that I'm using for search results pages.

I've changed the target for search results in Search Settings to point to my new search centre and the main search on the site now correctly shows results pages in my custom search centre.

However, the People Search web part is still stubbornly pointing to the default search centre.  I've updated both the Target URL and Advanced Target URL settings in web part options to point to my custom search centre but it seems to have no effect.

Is there another bit of config I'm missing to get this to work?

EDIT:  Just noticed that if I change the option in 'scopes dropdown' from default to target (which I assumed would use the URL I specify) in the misc settings) to default to contextual  it correctly goes to my new search site BUT adds additional parameters to the query string  (in this case it added cs=This%20Site&u=https%3A%2F%2Ftotaljobsgroup.sharepoint.com) that prevent the search from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that just using the normal Search web part and setting the target URL to be the peopleresults.aspx of the site I wanted to use worked.

My guess is that the people search webpart is preconfigured in some way to go to the default search centre regardless of user config.